# Unable to write into Excel using Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

My goal is to write data to excel depends on the length of a 2D array. Based on `String[][] types`, the length is 2. Thus, I would like my excel's output to be

```
      A       B  
1   word    word
2   word    word
3   word    word
4   word    word
```

However, this was what I get

```
      A       B  
1            word
2            word
3            word
4            word
```

Below are my codes.

```
    String[][] types = { {"type1", "value1"}, {"type2", "value2"},  };

        try {
            FileInputStream fis= new FileInputStream(new File(excelFile));       
            XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
            XSSFSheet worksheet = wb.getSheetAt(0); 

            for (int i = 0; i <4 ; i++) { // this will loop 4 times

            for (int a = 0; a < types.length ; a++) {    
                    inputs[a] = "word";
                XSSFRow row = worksheet.createRow(i);
                row.createCell(a).setCellValue(inputs[a]);
            }
            }
..
```

Any help with be appreciated :)

Comment: Your program logic is wrong. You should only create a new row for each i and not for each a too. So do moving the `XSSFRow row = worksheet.createRow(i);` out of the for a loop. `for (int i = 0; i <4 ; i++) { XSSFRow row = worksheet.createRow(i); for (int a = 0; a < types.length ; a++) { ... `.

Comment: @AxelRichter it works! Do u want to put your comment as an answer? So I can tick it?

Comment: No, it is so obvious that it is not worth an answer in my opinion. But you can answering your own question now. In the answer you should describing your new gained knowledge about why it had failed in your old code and why it works now in your new code.